# pgf-pie not properly rendering accented i - í

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgf-pie

In the legend of my pgf-pie chart, I am using accented i character - í. For some reason, it appears as a number with the accent sign instead of the actual letter when compiled.

MWE:

```
\documentclass[tikz, 12pt, a4paper]{report}
\usepackage[usenames, dvipsnames, rgb]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgf-pie}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows, positioning, shadows}
\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\pie[color={RedOrange, Dandelion, Goldenrod, SeaGreen, Thistle},sum=auto,text=legend]{10/Alín, 20/Balín, 30/Calín, 10/Dalín, 56/Elín}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

[image: screenshot]

How can this be fixed?

Comment: As a last resort, XeLaTeX compiles correctly.  Interestingly, even `Al\'in` does not work in pdflatex.

Comment: pgf-pie uses \i as loop variable, and so breaks its usage inside í.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

pgf-pie uses internally \i as loop variable when building the legend -- a rather bad choice when text is involved.  You can use T1 encoding, then internally \i is not used, and it doesn't matter that pgf-pie overwrites it:

```
\documentclass[tikz, 12pt, a4paper]{report}
\usepackage[usenames, dvipsnames, rgb]{xcolor}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgf-pie}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows, positioning, shadows}
\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\pie[color={RedOrange, Dandelion, Goldenrod, SeaGreen, Thistle},sum=auto,text=legend]{10/Alín, 20/Balín, 30/Calín, 10/Dalín, 56/Elín}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Great answer that diagnoses and resolves the issue!

Comment: Fixed in the next release.